# Why the need for capacitive loads?

Tags: filter, noise, load

Pioneer, Kenwood, Sony, Onkyo, Denon you name it, they all have a similar circuit like this:
[image: Generic schematic sample]

Why they use C1 and C3 for?
Thanks

Comment: High frequency noise filter? (RC low pass filters).

Comment: These capacitors indeed limit the high frequency content of the signal. Without them high frequency signals are not attenuated and my cause problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The low impedence of the capacitor at high frequency shunts high-frequency noise to ground.

For example, pickup of radio signals or electromagnetic interference may generate inaudible signals in your hi-fi but do cause the amplifier components to work harder, wasting energy, and risking driving the electronics into saturation. This could be difficult to debug as you can't hear the interference directly but only the side-effect symptoms of it.

Comment: In countries with GSM cell networks, there is this well-known "beeping pattern" in cheap desktop PC speakers just before the phone rings. This is the punishment for omitting C1. HF energy gets rectified on nonlinearities, so you get parasitic amplitude demodulation. Shunting the high frequency to ground prevents or minimizes the issue.